# How to handle static initialization when running unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have some code which runs fine, but I would also add unit tests for it too. And I have problem not with tests per se, but with static initialization (constructor and fields) -- they are not executed.

AFAIK static initialization is executed on the first "touch". And I have something like this (chain of dependency):

```
public class A 
{
   public static readonly AFoo = "afoo";
}

public class B 
{
   public static readonly BFoo = new BFoo(A.AFoo);
}

public class C 
{
   public static readonly CFoo = new CFoo(B.BFoo);
}
```

And when running unit tests I see nulls in random places, for example all of the sudden `A.AFoo` is not null, but `B.BFoo` is.

**Once again, when running code "normally" everything is fine.**

What should I do to make static initialization work as always?

*For the record the static fields I use are constants, usually `EmptyIdentifier`, `EmptyPosition`, `NoCoordinates` so I would not have to use something like `new Vector3d(0,0,0)` all the time.*

Comment: What unit test framework are you using?

Comment: I would love to see a piece of the actual test code that has such issues.

Comment: @MichaelLiu, generic MS which comes with VS 2010 (Ultimate).

Comment: @WiktorZychla, nice to see a fellow from Polish Usenet (pl.comp.programming if my memory serves me well) :-D Yes, I would love to paste it but the thing is many factors can cause such effects, like number of namespaces, number of projects, so I have to simplify it first, which is a task on its own. I hoped that also somebody experienced this problem and could write from the practical POV, not theoretical.

Comment: @greenoldman: memory serves you well regarding the usenet. As for your issue, there must be something specific because normally this should not just happen. A small, isolated example would be great and if you are not capable of reproducing the issue in such small example, you could possibly not be able to resolve the original one.

Answer (score 0):

The following test works fine:

```
using FluentAssertions;

[TestClass]
public class SomeTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTransitiveDependencies() 
    {
        C.CFoo.BFoo.str.Should().Be("afoo");
    }
}
```

I have defined the code similar to yours.

```
public class A { public static readonly string AFoo = "afoo"; }
public class B { public static readonly BFoo BFoo = new BFoo(A.AFoo); }
public class C { public static readonly CFoo CFoo = new CFoo(B.BFoo); }
```

But it didn't compile, though i added these classes.

```
public class BFoo
{
    public readonly string str;
    public BFoo(string str) {this.str = str;}
}

public class CFoo
{
    public readonly BFoo BFoo;
    public CFoo(BFoo bFoo) {this.BFoo = bFoo;}
}
```

Everything setup within in single project seems to work just fine.
Maybe we need some more information about your setup.

Toolchain: VS2012 IDE, .NET 4.5 runtime, Win7 OS

packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FluentAssertions" version="2.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```